# IPython: Protecting {} brackets in shell invocations

Tags: ipython

I've been playing a little with IPython and its ability to execute shell commands prefixed with a `!`. I've run into a problem that can be illustrated by the following example:

```
In [1]: filename="mytxtfile.txt"

In [2]: !echo $filename
mytxtfile.txt

In [3]: !echo ${filename}.bak
.txt.bak

In [4]: !echo ${filename}
.txt
```

I was under the impression that wrapping the name of the python variable in `{...}` would allow me to append something to it without a whitespace in between. Appending itself works, but apparently `${filename}` is **different** from `$filename` in IPython.

**Why is that and how would I append something to the value of a python variable during a shell invocation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found my mistake: There is no `$` in front of the protecting `{...}`.

```
In [5]: !echo {filename}.bak
mytxtfile.txt.bak
```

Reference: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#manual-capture-of-command-output

Comment: I think it's interesting that `${filename}` expands to just its extension. Did you find a reason for that?

Comment: yes, `{filename}` is expanded to `mytxtfile.txt` the shell receive `$mytxtfile.txt` and `$mytxtfile` is expanded to nothing by the shell. try `filename="PATH"` for example.

Comment: @Matt - I got that, I just wondered why `${filename}` expands to the file's suffix. It's just kind of non-intuitive, that's all...

Comment: @MattDMo that what I explained `${filename}`==>`$myfile.txt` but `$myfile`==`''` so `$myfile.txt` --> `.txt` where `==>`is expanded by IPython and `-->`expanded by shell...

Comment: @Matt OK, I understand now. Sorry for being a little dense :)

Comment: No problem, stackoverflow comment are sometime a little limited to do long explanation, and it took me some time to figure out why the first time too.